# Normal coordinates of a kahler manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(X, w)$ be a kahler manifold, and consider a sequence of $(1,1)$ forms $w_t = w + t i \partial \bar \partial f$. Want to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}S(w_t)|_{t = 0}$ in coordinates where $S(w_t)$ is the scalar curvature of $w_t$.

It is easy to calculate that $\frac{d}{dt}S(w_t)|_{t = 0} = - g^{j\bar q}(\partial_p \bar \partial_q f)g^{p \bar k}R_{j\bar k} - \Delta^2 f$, but I was told then that $\frac{d}{dt}S(w_t)|_{t = 0} = - \Delta^2 f - R^{\bar k j} \partial_j \partial_{\bar k}f$.

The last equality does make sense when we choose normal coordinates of $w$ at a point $p$, then does it boil down to showing that $R^{\bar k j} \partial_j \partial_{\bar k} f$ is invariant under coordinate change? How to show this?

Comment: It seems that $\partial_j \partial_{\bar k} f$ is just the $(i, k)$ component of the form $\partial \bar\partial f$, so it is well defined.

Comment: Yes, but why does the equality hold?

Comment: Are you confused about deriving the (1st) equation, or about the equality of those two equalities?

Comment: I am only confused about the last one(the one on the fourth line) where the inverse of the metric is no longer there. I assume one can get rid of the inverse of the metric choosing a normal coordinate. But you can only do that at one single point, how does one prove the equality in a whole chart?

Answer (score 1):

It is the definition of $R^{\bar kj}$ that

$$ R^{\bar kj}= g^{i\bar k} g^{j\bar l} R_{i\bar l}$$

and so

$$R^{\bar k j} \partial_j \partial_{\bar k}f = g^{i\bar k} g^{j\bar l} R_{i\bar l}\partial_j \partial_{\bar k}f = g^{j\bar q}(\partial_p \bar \partial_q f)g^{p \bar k}R_{j\bar k}$$